# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

Tags: php

```
'light' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Light Themes from jQuery UI', 'ipt_fsqm' ),
            'themes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'label' => 'Default Theme',
                    'src' => array(),
                    'colors' => array( 'f4fcfd', '333333', '3ac7ff', '01a8bd' ),
                ),
                'excite-bike' => array(
                    'label' => 'Excite Bike',
                    'src' => array(
                        'common' => $path . 'excite-bike/form.css',
                        '1.9' => $path . 'excite-bike/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                        '1.10' => $path . 'excite-bike/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                    ),
                    'colors' => array( 'eeeeee', '282828', '2293f7', 'e69700' ),
                ),
                'cupertino' => array(
                    'label' => 'Cupertino',
                    'src' => array(
                        'common' => $path . 'cupertino/form.css',
                        '1.9' => $path . 'cupertino/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                        '1.10' => $path . 'cupertino/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                    ),
                    'colors' => array( 'f2f5f7', '362b36', 'aed0ea', '74b2e2' ),
                ),
                'blitzer' => array(
                    'label' => 'Blitzer',
                    'src' => array(
                        'common' => $path . 'blitzer/form.css',
                        '1.9' => $path . 'blitzer/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                        '1.10' => $path . 'blitzer/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                    ),
                    'colors' => array( 'ffffff', '333333', 'e3a1a1', 'cc0000' ),
                ),
                'black-tie' => array(
                    'label' => 'Black Tie',
                    'src' => array(
                        'common' => $path . 'black-tie/form.css',
                        '1.9' => $path . 'black-tie/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                        '1.10' => $path . 'black-tie/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                    ),
                    'colors' => array( 'f9f9f9', '000000', 'cccccc', '777777' ),
                ),
                'hot-sneaks' => array(
                    'label' => 'Hot Sneaks',
                    'src' => array(
                        'common' => $path . 'hot-sneaks/form.css',
                        '1.9' => $path . 'hot-sneaks/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                        '1.10' => $path . 'hot-sneaks/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                    ),
                    'colors' => array( 'ffffff', '232323', 'ccd232', 'db4865' ),
                ),
                'humanity' => array(
                    'label' => 'Humanity',
                    'src' => array(
                        'common' => $path . 'humanity/form.css',
                        '1.9' => $path . 'humanity/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                        '1.10' => $path . 'humanity/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                    ),
                    'colors' => array( 'f4f0ec', '232323', 'f5ad66', 'd49768', 'cb842e' ),
                ),
                'redmond' => array(
                    'label' => 'Redmond',
                    'src' => array(
                        'common' => $path . 'redmond/form.css',
                        '1.9' => $path . 'redmond/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                        '1.10' => $path . 'redmond/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                    ),
                    'colors' => array( 'fcfdfd', '333333', 'accbe3', '5c9ccc' ),
                ),
                'pepper-grinder' => array(
                    'label'             ),
        'Supermercado_One' => array(
            'label' => "'Supermercado One', cursive",
            'include' => 'Supermercado+One',
        ),
        'Averia_Libre' => array(
            'label' => "'Averia Libre', cursive",
            'include' => 'Averia+Libre',
        ),
        'Croissant_One' => array(
            'label' => "'Croissant One', cursive",
            'include' => 'Croissant+One',
        ),
        'Averia_Gruesa_Libre' => array(
            'label' => "'Averia Gruesa Libre', cursive",
            'include' => 'Averia+Gruesa+Libre',
        ),
        'Overlock' => array(
            'label' => "'Overlock', cursive",
            'include' => 'Overlock',
        ),
        'Lobster_Two' => array(
            'label' => "'Lobster Two', cursive",
            'include' => 'Lobster+Two',
        ),
        'Bevan' => array(
            'label' => "'Bevan', cursive",
            'include' => 'Bevan',
        ),
        'Pompiere' => array(
            'label' => "'Pompiere', cursive",
            'include' => 'Pompiere',
        ),
        'Kelly_Slab' => array(
            'label' => "'Kelly Slab', cursive",
            'include' => 'Kelly+Slab',
        ),
        'Carter_One' => array(
            'label' => "'Carter One', cursive",
            'include' => 'Carter+One',
        ),
        'Inconsolata' => array(
            'label' => "'Inconsolata'",
            'include' => 'Inconsolata',
        ),
        'Ubuntu_Mono' => array(
            'label' => "'Ubuntu Mono'",
            'include' => 'Ubuntu+Mono',
        ),
        'Droid_Sans_Mono' => array(
            'label' => "'Droid Sans Mono'",
            'include' => 'Droid+Sans+Mono',
        ),
        'Source_Code_Pro' => array(
            'label' => "'Source Code Pro'",
            'include' => 'Source+Code+Pro',
        ),
        'Nova_Mono' => array(
            'label' => "'Nova Mono'",
            'include' => 'Nova+Mono',
        ),
        'PT_Mono' => array(
            'label' => "'PT Mono'",
            'include' => 'PT+Mono',
        ),
        'Cutive_Mono' => array(
            'label' => "'Cutive Mono'",
            'include' => 'Cutive+Mono',
        ),
        'Crete_Round' => array(
            'label' => "'Crete Round', serif",
            'include' => 'Crete Round',
        ),
        'EB_Garamond' => array(
            'label' => "'EB Garamond', serif",
            'include' => 'EB+Garamond',
        ),
        'Cardo' => array(
            'label' => "'Cardo', serif",
            'include' => 'Cardo',
        ),
        'Fanwood_Text' => array(
            'label' => "'Fanwood Text', serif",
            'include' => 'Fanwood+Text',
        ),
        'Trocchi' => array(
            'label' => "'Trocchi', serif",
            'include' => 'Trocchi',
        ),
        'Fauna_One' => array(
            'label' => "'Fauna One', serif",
            'include' => 'Fauna+One',
        ),
        'Prata' => array(
            'label' => "'Prata', serif",
            'include' => 'Prata',
        ),
    );
```

its saying the error is at the last code );
i couldnt find wats going on wrong ..
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

on line 1660 which is the last line above.. 
tyvm whoever can help <3

Comment: don't show complete array. just the error description and only that line where error occure(include 2-3 line upper and down one also with that line).

Comment: Remove that `,` before `);` your last line

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing ) somewhere in your array. Find it, fix it. Even PHPSTorm says it's missing. My guess, edit the last ); as ), );

Comment: This actually helped me with the problem, it wasn't the solution but it helped me figure out what was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 ) in the end of array use some php editor like netbean to check your array formation

```
$array = array(
    'light' => array(
        'label' => __('Light Themes from jQuery UI', 'ipt_fsqm'),
        'themes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'label' => 'Default Theme',
                'src' => array(),
                'colors' => array('f4fcfd', '333333', '3ac7ff', '01a8bd'),
            ),
            'excite-bike' => array(
                'label' => 'Excite Bike',
                'src' => array(
                    'common' => $path . 'excite-bike/form.css',
                    '1.9' => $path . 'excite-bike/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                    '1.10' => $path . 'excite-bike/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                ),
                'colors' => array('eeeeee', '282828', '2293f7', 'e69700'),
            ),
            'cupertino' => array(
                'label' => 'Cupertino',
                'src' => array(
                    'common' => $path . 'cupertino/form.css',
                    '1.9' => $path . 'cupertino/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                    '1.10' => $path . 'cupertino/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                ),
                'colors' => array('f2f5f7', '362b36', 'aed0ea', '74b2e2'),
            ),
            'blitzer' => array(
                'label' => 'Blitzer',
                'src' => array(
                    'common' => $path . 'blitzer/form.css',
                    '1.9' => $path . 'blitzer/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                    '1.10' => $path . 'blitzer/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                ),
                'colors' => array('ffffff', '333333', 'e3a1a1', 'cc0000'),
            ),
            'black-tie' => array(
                'label' => 'Black Tie',
                'src' => array(
                    'common' => $path . 'black-tie/form.css',
                    '1.9' => $path . 'black-tie/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                    '1.10' => $path . 'black-tie/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                ),
                'colors' => array('f9f9f9', '000000', 'cccccc', '777777'),
            ),
            'hot-sneaks' => array(
                'label' => 'Hot Sneaks',
                'src' => array(
                    'common' => $path . 'hot-sneaks/form.css',
                    '1.9' => $path . 'hot-sneaks/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                    '1.10' => $path . 'hot-sneaks/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                ),
                'colors' => array('ffffff', '232323', 'ccd232', 'db4865'),
            ),
            'humanity' => array(
                'label' => 'Humanity',
                'src' => array(
                    'common' => $path . 'humanity/form.css',
                    '1.9' => $path . 'humanity/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                    '1.10' => $path . 'humanity/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                ),
                'colors' => array('f4f0ec', '232323', 'f5ad66', 'd49768', 'cb842e'),
            ),
            'redmond' => array(
                'label' => 'Redmond',
                'src' => array(
                    'common' => $path . 'redmond/form.css',
                    '1.9' => $path . 'redmond/1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css',
                    '1.10' => $path . 'redmond/1.10/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
                ),
                'colors' => array('fcfdfd', '333333', 'accbe3', '5c9ccc'),
            ),
            'pepper-grinder' => array(
                'label'),
            'Supermercado_One' => array(
                'label' => "'Supermercado One', cursive",
                'include' => 'Supermercado+One',
            ),
            'Averia_Libre' => array(
                'label' => "'Averia Libre', cursive",
                'include' => 'Averia+Libre',
            ),
            'Croissant_One' => array(
                'label' => "'Croissant One', cursive",
                'include' => 'Croissant+One',
            ),
            'Averia_Gruesa_Libre' => array(
                'label' => "'Averia Gruesa Libre', cursive",
                'include' => 'Averia+Gruesa+Libre',
            ),
            'Overlock' => array(
                'label' => "'Overlock', cursive",
                'include' => 'Overlock',
            ),
            'Lobster_Two' => array(
                'label' => "'Lobster Two', cursive",
                'include' => 'Lobster+Two',
            ),
            'Bevan' => array(
                'label' => "'Bevan', cursive",
                'include' => 'Bevan',
            ),
            'Pompiere' => array(
                'label' => "'Pompiere', cursive",
                'include' => 'Pompiere',
            ),
            'Kelly_Slab' => array(
                'label' => "'Kelly Slab', cursive",
                'include' => 'Kelly+Slab',
            ),
            'Carter_One' => array(
                'label' => "'Carter One', cursive",
                'include' => 'Carter+One',
            ),
            'Inconsolata' => array(
                'label' => "'Inconsolata'",
                'include' => 'Inconsolata',
            ),
            'Ubuntu_Mono' => array(
                'label' => "'Ubuntu Mono'",
                'include' => 'Ubuntu+Mono',
            ),
            'Droid_Sans_Mono' => array(
                'label' => "'Droid Sans Mono'",
                'include' => 'Droid+Sans+Mono',
            ),
            'Source_Code_Pro' => array(
                'label' => "'Source Code Pro'",
                'include' => 'Source+Code+Pro',
            ),
            'Nova_Mono' => array(
                'label' => "'Nova Mono'",
                'include' => 'Nova+Mono',
            ),
            'PT_Mono' => array(
                'label' => "'PT Mono'",
                'include' => 'PT+Mono',
            ),
            'Cutive_Mono' => array(
                'label' => "'Cutive Mono'",
                'include' => 'Cutive+Mono',
            ),
            'Crete_Round' => array(
                'label' => "'Crete Round', serif",
                'include' => 'Crete Round',
            ),
            'EB_Garamond' => array(
                'label' => "'EB Garamond', serif",
                'include' => 'EB+Garamond',
            ),
            'Cardo' => array(
                'label' => "'Cardo', serif",
                'include' => 'Cardo',
            ),
            'Fanwood_Text' => array(
                'label' => "'Fanwood Text', serif",
                'include' => 'Fanwood+Text',
            ),
            'Trocchi' => array(
                'label' => "'Trocchi', serif",
                'include' => 'Trocchi',
            ),
            'Fauna_One' => array(
                'label' => "'Fauna One', serif",
                'include' => 'Fauna+One',
            ),
            'Prata' => array(
                'label' => "'Prata', serif",
                'include' => 'Prata',
            ),
        )
    )
);
```